# Jasmine expect is not defined in intellij

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, jasmine

I am new to typescript and am struggling to run individual jasmine tests in my IDE (Intellij or Webstorm are not working).

An easy example is if I try to run the jasmine examples loaded with the `jasmine examples`. When I try to run them manually in intellij I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: expect is not defined
    at Context.<anonymous> (spec/jasmine_examples/PlayerSpec.js:14:5)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:458:21)
```

When I run `jasmine` from the command line it runs the tests fine and they pass.

I have tried installing karma with npm and running a karma intellij plugin but doesn't do anything.

What am I missing here? Something obvious I'm assuming!

Comment: How do you run it? Please paste the full console output here, including a command line. Looks as if you are passing the test file directly to Node.js, not using the `jasmine` test runner

Comment: I am running it directly from intellij (as a single test). So the output is what you see above. The problem was with the intellij test runner. Intellij was defaulting to mocha. I haven't found any great jasmine runner for intellij tho, but from what little I understand jasmine runner will only be able to cater for unit tests anyway which is more limited than I'd hoped for. Have just decided to run with mocha, chai and sinon for now (which is annoying because we have jasmine handling our front end tests so wanted to avoid different frameworks).